# CodeMemberField cutting off dictionary

Tags: c#

The Issue

```
private Dictionary<String, Action<Writer, Queue<DataSerializer> (CUTOFF HERE)
Dictionary<String, Action<Writer, Queue<DataSerializer>, System.Int32, SendTo, Peer, Peer[]>>;
```

I created a Fiddle to show the exact problem I am having, I know linking externally is looked down on but for the most part I have shown my work and allow the execution of the application with ease. The end result is the Dictionary cutting off after the Queue, I am not sure why its happening but it is.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eBQZtf)

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    private static CodeCompileUnit compileUnit;
    private static CodeNamespace unitNamespace;
    private static CodeTypeDeclaration classDefinition;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started Compile");
        compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
        unitNamespace = new CodeNamespace("DarkSide");
        classDefinition = new CodeTypeDeclaration("ExampleOfCuttoff");
        classDefinition.Attributes = (MemberAttributes)24578;
        SetupDocument();
        CreateDictionary();
        Compile();
    }
    public static void SetupDocument()
    {
        unitNamespace.Types.Add(classDefinition);
        unitNamespace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System.Net"));
        unitNamespace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));
        unitNamespace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System.Collections.Generic"));
        compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(unitNamespace);
    }
    private static void CreateDictionary()
    {
        var send = new CodeMemberField("Dictionary<String, Action<Writer, Queue<DataSerializer>, System.Int32, SendTo, Peer, Peer[]>> sendMethods =", 
                                  "Dictionary<String, Action<Writer, Queue<DataSerializer>, System.Int32, SendTo, Peer, Peer[]>>");
        send.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private;
        classDefinition.Members.Add(send);
    }
    private static void Compile()
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        var writer = new StringWriter(result);
        var cCompiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        cCompiler.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(compileUnit, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
        writer.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Result: "+ result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to draw a conclusion that the CodeMemberField cuts off the Actions at three parameters. In turn I have to put the send type into a struct and pass that through as the third parameter.